# Codeigniter reCaptcha v3 with cUrl

Tags: codeigniter, recaptcha

I have a form integrated with invisible reCaptcha.

Verification is performed on a function within the Controller.

The call to google is made using file_get_content and if no response is obtained, the call is made using curl.

This is the function

```
public function verify_captcha()
        {

            $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptchaResponse'];

            log_message('info', $recaptcha_response);           

            // Build POST request:

            $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'; 
            $recaptcha_secret = 'My KEY'; 
            $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptchaResponse']; 
            $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response); 
            $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha,true);      


            if(!$recaptcha)
            {
                // call curl to POST request

                log_message('info', 'Call CURL');       
                $data = array( 'secret' => $recaptcha_secret, 'response' => $recaptcha_response); 
                //$curlConfig = array( CURLOPT_URL => $recaptcha_url, CURLOPT_POST => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data ); 
                $ch = curl_init(); 

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  $recaptcha_url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);             

                $response = curl_exec($ch);                 

                curl_close($ch);
                $recaptcha = json_decode($response, true);  


                ob_start();
                var_dump($recaptcha);
                $result = ob_get_contents(); //or ob_get_clean()
                log_message('info', $result);               



                if (array_key_exists('error-codes', $recaptcha))
                {

                    log_message('error',  'Error reCaptcha '.$recaptcha['error-codes'][0]);

                }               



                if ($recaptcha["success"] == '1') 
                { 
                    if ($recaptcha["score"] >= 0.5) 
                    {

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                  log_message('error',  'Error reCaptcha no Success');
                }
       else
       {
         log_message('info', 'Call file_get_content');
       }    
}
```

These are the messages of the log file

```
ERROR - 2020-03-18 09:54:31 --> Severity: Warning  --> file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known /mysite/application/controllers/captcha.php 1362
ERROR - 2020-03-18 09:54:31 --> Severity: Warning  --> file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LfP26QUAAAAAHilJfguEgIcgOBkTg2soD7oCQIh&amp;response=03AERD8XpOL7956DMd7dhiqasH4fK2iNjtBFBJdw3OynXGeAFBMmSqqtjsqXFW97rv-kD_H-y6aLrL1VLMkwg222Y7BoNnaB_zQ7y2NzXVtlIsWYwIw9BSbUdFdSylq4dNjO5j5Jo1xvjPotvMFuddnC5YVRC1wnk7HESqv8hvRU40x9pNpoQ-sIaXcAN8BdBgleXFufmmNoMzuh3PCvgT3RkIj1TsTs-ltM9LyVbLtFnFPbTkHZqpQjppMkHCcw87u3xqbr23EJkusR_U2vFwJTAJU9p-Z27sDuiKmEMsjJ2O1i3Wnxm9yq4HiEI2vnh420VDnPZEYRbXuLLSGhGuPciGQ3mtp07tjn265oyYbcFp2s9GentdUpPWRCxWfySTa6du7dzzSHkqPMKcPf6LmfVtICkTJf4y-w): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known /mysite/application/controllers/captcha.php 1362
INFO  - 2020-03-18 09:54:31 --> Call CURL
INFO  - 2020-03-18 09:54:31 --> NULL
```

The call to file_get_content shows error and returns nothing with curl.

What may be happening?

Thanks

Comment: when using `file_get_contents()` you're essentially sending a `GET` request which is on many levels incorrect (for starters, you'd be passing along your secret key in the clear, which creates an attack vector from malicious users, even the least skilled ones). You MUST use CURL because the recaptcha verification expects a `POST` and will probably fail deliberately if it doesn't receive a `POST`

Comment: Ok, but in the code, if it doesn't return anything file_get_content makes the call by cUrl, but it returns NULL

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but this may be a conflict with the output buffering in your code. Can you try removing the three lines starting at `ob_start()` and change the fourth line to `log_message('info', $recaptcha); ` and see what (if anything) gets logged?

Answer (score 0):

If  you totally, absolutely need to use file_get_contents, I'll share with you a helper function I have, which you can adapt to your own needs

```
function validate_recaptcha_response($recaptcha_response)
{
    $api_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $api_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $remoteip = '';

    $data = array('secret' => $api_secret, 'response' => $recaptcha_response);
    $options = array(
        'http'  => array(
            'header'    => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'    => 'POST',
            'content'   => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context);

    $captcha_response = json_decode($result, true);

    $r = array(
        'success'       => $captcha_response['success'],
        'timestamp'     => $captcha_response['challenge_ts'],
        'hostname'      => $captcha_response['hostname'],
        'error_codes'   => (isset($captcha_response['error-codes'])) ? $captcha_response['error-codes'] : null,
    );

    return $r;  
}
```

I call this from any controller that gets the recaptcha response (the helper is autoloaded) using something like

`$recaptcha_check = validate_recaptcha_response($var_where_you_store_the_recaptcha_response);`

Please note that I'm adding the `$options` array to build a `POST`, defining a header, the method and use `http_build_query()` and `stream_context_create()` before `file_get_contents()` in order to query the data.

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary to use file_get_contents

Comment: When I use this function, the line to call to `file_get_contents` is always returning `false`. All the parameters are correct. Is this because `allow_url_fopen` is set `Off` in the `php.ini` file?

Comment: Yes, very likely. To use `file_get_contents` with a remote URL instead of a local file, you need to have the `allow_url_fopen` enabled

Answer (score 0):

Please Follow the bellow Steps to integrate Recaptcha v3 in Codeigniter versions bellow 4 (3.1.9) or others.

```
    Step #1: Create Recaptcha v3 for your domain and keep the site_key & secret_key.
      [https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key][1]

    Step #2: Add the bellow Javascirpt codes with replacement of your site_key & secret_key inside Head section of your Form page.
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var review_recaptcha_widget;
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        if($('#review_recaptcha').length) {
            review_recaptcha_widget = grecaptcha.render('review_recaptcha', {
              'sitekey' : 'recaptcha_site_key_v3',
              'secretkey' : 'recaptcha_secret_key_v3'
            });
        }
      };      
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>

    Step #3:Browse the page, you will see the new recaptcha in right bottom corner of page, Done, thats it.
```